# Tymon JWTAuth class not found

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-artisan

I want to use laravel for building api.
I installed JWTAuth from installation guide on [wiki page](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation). When I want to use `vendor:publish`, I get this error: [image]

After 3days searching on Google, I can not find a solution that working for me. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply means you have not added `JWTAuthServiceProvider` to list of Laravel Service providers.

Go to `config/app.php` and add `JWTAuthServiceProvider` to providers list

Like so:

```
'providers' => [
   ...

   Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,

   ...
]
```

Secondly since these error occurs only in console run:

```
composer update --no-scripts
composer update
```

Comment: I added this before. I think my problem is related to composer auto loader and maybe it's not working. How can I find composer auto load files work correctly?

Comment: Thank you @Digitlimit but still I have problem :\

Comment: You need to verify Tymon\AUth service provider is in vendor/jwt-auth/src/providers

Comment: YES! Thank you @Digitlimit my problem was in my folders structure.

Answer (score 4):

For latest version. Please use following code in providers array in config file

For laravel

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class
```

For Lumen : open app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php and add the following to the register() method.

```
$this->app->register(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I get the following error (using Laravel 5.4) after adding the provider. `Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\NamshiAdapter' not found`

Comment: Working on laravel 5.8

Answer (score 3):

add `"tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"` to composer.json and command

```
composer update
```

on app/config.php add this to `providers`

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
```

and on app/config.php add this on `aliases`

```
'JWTAuth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class,
```

tested on `laravel 5.5` and  `tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12"`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and in what way it differs from the current accepted answer.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.